# Help identifying component with top marking C3008

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Need community help in order to identify component in the photo. Already searched on the Texas Instruments site, but couldn't find it. It's a 40 pin device.

It's a power management IC on a ps vita 2000. Chances are this has been a custom made ic?

[image: photo showing unknown device on a PCB]

Comment: What device is it used in?  Can you  give any indication of the function of the part?

Comment: Hi Peter and thanks. It's a power management IC on a ps vita 2000. Chances are this has been a custom made ic?

Comment: Please put that information in your question, not as a comment.  The more information you can provide about the part and its use, the better your chance of getting the thing identified.